# Add jquery snippet to WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add some jQuery to my WordPress website, but it won't work yet.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb71gj9h/#&togetherjs=RGBzMyqBd1

The code works like a charm, but it's hard for me to implement on my WordPress website.

Where do I add this little piece of jQuery?

```
if (jQuery("span").hasClass("swatch-class1 selected")) {
  jQuery(".class3").addClass("displaynone");
}
```

Possibly I have to build this in a way that it is a jQuery 'function', but I don't know how.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: "it won't work yet." Is pretty vague.  Is your browser reporting any JS errors?  Many themes in Wordpress are set up to use JQuery in no conflict mode, you might just have to change the dollar signs to "JQuery", good luck!

Comment: add code in your script file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use $. you have to use "jQuery" in place of $.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you want to add some JS code to your WP site. You can add something like this to function.php which is placed in theme directory

```
function my_own_js() {
    echo '<script>/* Code */</script>';
    // or
    echo '<script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_own_js');
```